# How to decide whether to optimize model hyperparameters on a development set or by cross-validation?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization, hyperparameter

Suppose I have a machine learning model. I've seen 2 ways to **optimize its hyperparameters**: **(i)** Cross-Validation and **(ii)** Development Set. Are they parallel to each other? If so, what are the advantages and disadvantages? How should I decide which one to use? And if not, what's the workflow like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The development set, in other words, validation set or holdout set is like executing cross-validation for one fold only. It's faster, therefore cheaper. Typically, cross-validation is more robust because the performance is averaged across several tests instead of one. This might make sense when dealing with smaller datasets. When, data is not a problem, their performances should converge. When the training is expensive, like in deep neural nets, it'd be impractical to use cross-validation because we'll train the neural net over and over for each fold.

Comment: *several tests* or *several sets*?

Comment: I think both make sense. I called performance evaluation over a fold as a test.

Comment: Thank you! This is very clarifying!